# can I save my current dir and windows in cmder?

Tags: cmd, cmder

## How to save my current setup in Cmder

I use Cmder on windows for  all of my deving. I use a separate front and back end for my MEAN applications and also gulp for javascript minification. Also to run mongodb I use the cmder.

My window looks like this once everything is running

[image]

Every time I start work on my project I have to open all these windows and run the cd commands to get to their respective folders. I was wondering if there was a way to save the session so that I can have all my windows open automatically in their correct dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use startup settings

You can write startup settings that allow you to execute a series of tasks on startup under

> Settings > Startup > Tasks

Here you can define what shell starts and what tasks it should perform, with this you can open new tabs and `cd` to where you need to work.

A simpler version of this is to just go as far as

> Settings > Startup

and find the radio button "Auto save/restore opened tabs", this will at least open up you Cmder where you left off, without the cmd's running.

Hope this helps people who use many windows on startup.